# Investigating the performance of a Ruby gem with Rust extension

Tags: ruby, rust, graphql-ruby

### Introduction

After reading [Ruby Outperforms C](https://railsatscale.com/2023-08-29-ruby-outperforms-c/) article I got curious how Rust would perform. So I started working on a Ruby gem with Rust extension that implements a GraphQL parser. For the parser implementation I'm using [graphql_parser](https://docs.rs/graphql-parser/latest/graphql_parser/) crate. To interact with Ruby runtime I'm using [magnus](https://docs.rs/magnus/latest/magnus/) following [this guide](https://bundler.io/blog/2023/01/31/rust-gem-skeleton.html).

### My approach

I wrote some Rust code that traverses the AST produced by `graphql_parser` and translates it to Ruby objects (hashes and arrays). The code looks like this:

```rust
fn parse(query: String) -> Result<RHash, Error> {
    match parse_query::<String>(&query) {
        Ok(r) => return Ok(translation::translate_document(&r)),
        Err(e) => return Err(Error::new(exception::runtime_error(), e.to_string())),
    }
}

fn translate_document(doc: &Document<'_, String>) -> RHash {
    let hash = build_ruby_node("document");
    let definitions = RArray::new();
    for x in doc.definitions.iter() {
        definitions.push(translate_definition(x)).unwrap();
    }
    hash.aset(Symbol::new("definitions"), definitions).unwrap();
    return hash;
}

fn translate_definition(definition: &Definition<'_, String>) -> RHash {
    return match definition {
        Definition::Operation(operation) => translate_operation_definition(operation),
        Definition::Fragment(fragment) => translate_fragment_definition(fragment),
    };
}

// Many more functions that follow the structure produced by graphql_parser...

fn build_ruby_node(node_type: &str) -> RHash {
    let hash = RHash::new();
    hash.aset(Symbol::new("node_type"), Symbol::new(node_type))
        .unwrap();
    return hash;
}
```

Essentially I have a bunch of recursive functions that closely mirror the document structure defined by `graphql_parser`. Full code is in [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/fpacanowski/rust_graphql_parser/tree/deed9dd26d0749c1469f15bedb496e3bb58eb0b5/ext/rust_graphql_parser/src).

### Benchmark

I was hoping the described approach would have a performance similar to the following:

```rust
fn parse_raw(query: String) -> String {
    let ast = parse_query::<&str>(&query);
    return format!("#{:?}",ast);
}
```

My idea was that this does essentially the same thing: traverses the AST and produces a Ruby object with the same data. However the benchmark shows that my code is actually ~5x slower:

```
$ bundle exec ruby benchmark.rb
Warming up --------------------------------------
               parse     4.000  i/100ms
           parse_raw    24.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
               parse     53.968  (± 3.7%) i/s -    272.000  in   5.050661s
           parse_raw    245.115  (± 2.4%) i/s -      1.248k in   5.094948s
```

I ran this with Ruby 3.2.2 (`ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]`).

### Question

I'm a Rust beginner. I'd like to understand where the performance bottleneck in my code is. Am I doing something obviously wrong? Is allocating Ruby objects just inherently slow? Is there a way I can make this gem more performant?

Comment: First, the `format!()` will do much less allocations. Second, I assume creating Ruby objects requires calling CRuby APIs and that has some bookkeeping needed, more than just allocating the objects.

Comment: I don't know Ruby well enough, but in Python if I'd had such situation the solution is to pass as less data as possible between Rust and Python. For example, instead of allocating the whole parsed tree and return it to Python, you may as well port the execution code into Rust and have only the interface of `execute(data_to_send_to_graphql)`.

Comment: It would be more work, but since Ruby does duck typing, it would probably be more efficient to return an object which simply wraps your rust data and which has a hash-like interface. I don't know how magnus does it but in the C API I'd use `TypedData_Wrap_Struct` and `TypedData_Get_Struct` to define alloc/init methods for my object.